# Make white transparent on the outside only

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I am using imagick with php to modify uploaded images. I want to remove the white around an image to make it have a transparent background. Using this:

```
$val = 65535/15;
$val = intval($val/1);//divide by 1 means accept full fuzz at the moment
$image->paintTransparentImage("rgb(255,255,255)", 0.0, intval(1*$val);
```

However, if I upload a picture of someone with white teeth, it makes their teeth vanish! So am i missing something that I could do to prevent that or should I just drop the idea?

Comment: The fuzz measure on [`paintTransparentImage()`](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.painttransparentimage.php) is not a magic wand like selection tool, it's a colour tolerance measure.  It takes all pixels of the specified colour (within the fuzz tolerance) all over the image and converts them to transparency.

Comment: I got that, is there anything that acts like a magic wand? Perhaps I could change it to fuchsia and change the color value in paintTransparentImage

Comment: Suggested reading: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#bg_remove

Comment: Thanks both of you, got me on the right track for a solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the comments I came up with this solution:

```
//15 is the degree of fuzz user can choose in page
$val = 65535/15;
//divide by fuzz dilution, 1 is none
$val = floatval($val/1);
//create white border
$image->borderImage ( "rgb(255,255,255)" , 1 , 1 );
//make all white fill fuchsia 
$image->floodFillPaintImage ( "rgb(255, 0, 255)" ,$userfuzz*$val, "rgb(255,255,255)", 0 , 0, false);
//make fuchsia transparent
$image->paintTransparentImage("rgb(255,0,255)", 0.0, 10); 
//remove border 1px that was added above
$image->shaveImage ( 1 , 1 );
```

Just have to let people know that fuchsia is incompatible with the website ;)