# Make image background transparent by detecting Object edges using Imagick?

Tags: php, image-processing, transparency, imagick

I am trying to make background of image transparent.Using following code

```
$strInputFile = 'test.jpg';
$target = 'test_transparent.png';
$im = new Imagick($strInputFile);
$im->paintTransparentImage($im->getImageBackgroundColor(), 0, 7000);
$im->setImageFormat('png');
$im->writeImage($target);
$im->destroy();
```

This code is working great for few images.But for most of the images output doesn't come out well.
Wanted result come from script.

[image: wanted output]

Unwanted result come from script.

[image: Unwanted result]

Is it possible to detect edges of model and remove color before model?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make white transparent on the outside only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120545/make-white-transparent-on-the-outside-only)

Comment: Maybe show your starting images!